# FeedWordPress Featured Image

Tags: wordpress, rss, feed

I'm using feedwordpress plugin to auto import posts from one site to my other site, but it does not import the featured image, how can I make it import it?

Comment: Joey, you'll get better help if you provide more info. Maybe a link to the plug-in and include any relevant details such as whether or not that plugin claims to actually import featured images?

Comment: Hello Jason, actually this plugin doesn't claim to do that, I used a custom PHP code for few years on REST API but suddenly it stopped working a while ago, and I can't get it to work, although no changes were made to it in the past 3 years, so I'm trying to get an alternative, feedwordpress does the job really but I want to import featured image as well, or make the images in the beginning of the post to show in the posts page in the post excerpt

Comment: prolly need to share some more info... I'd also think about posting to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Jason, I will try posting there.
Also, that was the original code that suddenly stopped working for no reason
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248094/wordpress-php-error-getting-posts-from-another-wordpress-blog